# Libraries for text manipulation

Tags: string, animation, text, char, processing

So...

I plan on doing an animation that pulls all the text from the screen to the middle and lets it pulse like a heart. For that I checked if I'm able to manipulate whole Strings and Chars the way I'm able to manipulate circles, for example. I found the libraries Nexttext and Fontastic, but those seem to be outdated, therefore I can't use them with Processing 3.0. Than there is the library Geomerative, which I manged to install through Processings library manager, but this one yields the error "duplicate libraries", which I can't find a , for me understandable, workaround for. I'm also using minim, since I combine the pulse with music input, minim works fine though.

Thus I'm asking if anyone here has an idea on how to fix this error, make the outdated libraries run or maybe someone has an alternative way/library to manipulate text.

Apparently the processing forum is not that active, hence I'm asking here, there was one suggestions tho, that I should search for similar Java libraries, which I yet have to do.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean when you say you want to pull text from the screen? Do you mean you want to get text from another application and copy it into Processing? Or are you just talking about doing something inside the Processing window?

If you're just talking about manipulating text within the Processing window, then I'm not sure why you need a library for this. Processing has several functions that allow you to draw text, change its font, size, positioning, etc.

Anyway, the issue you've encountered is a [known bug](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/3579). Looks like the only solution for now is to use an old version of Processing. You can download them from the same place you downloaded Processing 3.

Comment: I'm talking about something in the Processing window. My plan was to display a text, that is than getting pulled in to the center of the screen and than starts to pulsate. But I didn't find a way to neatly format (centered with prober line breaks) a longer text, so I was looking for font specific librariers. But it appears there's no such thing, so instead of using a wall of text I'd have to try with just a single word.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Geomerative](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/) and [Fontastic](http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/) work with Processing 3.2.3

Bare in mind is the bug Kevin mentioned.
However, the only issue I had was compiling examples that had this line:

```
import processing.opengl.*;
```

Simply remove or comment this line and the example should compile

Comment: I should note that I was using Processing 3.1.1, so this is probably the correct answer!

Comment: The issue was that when importing Geomerative through processing it would also add `import org.apache.batik.svggen.font.*;` and `import org.apache.batik.svggen.font.table.*;`, which cause the error to appear. I thought that after removing those lines I wouldn't be able to use Geomerative turns out it works just fine.

Comment: Nice find ! I've never seen these imports in the examples, but it sounds about right :) From what I can gather if there's a library used by more than one other library, the imports will clash in Processing 3. Glad you figured it out